# Laravel upgrade to 4.2 - mcrypt extension required

Tags: macos, laravel, xampp, mcrypt

I have problems when trying to update laravel 4.1 to 4.2.

I started that project on ubuntu, then got a new macbook pro and it looks like I'm missing something.

I'm using XAMPP 1.8.3

When I

```
composer update
```

I get the following error

```
Mcrypt PHP extension required.
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error
```

After few googling, found homebrew, then it's easy

```
brew install mcrypt
```

but I get the following warning

```
Warning: mcrypt-2.6.8 already installed
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I had a __super fun__ time installing mcrypt on Maverics and Mountain Lion.  I ended up installing it from scratch as `homebew` didn't seems to work in my case.  You might have better luck though.  Since it is installed, do you have `extension=mcrypt.so` in your `php.ini`?  Check out [this tutorial](http://jenssegers.be/blog/49/installing-the-php-mcrypt-extension-on-osx-10-9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your macbook pro is running Mavericks, the problem is most likely in your `$PATH` variable. The php command defaults to the built in php that ships with your mac. You can verify this by entering in terminal `echo $PATH;`

If it points to `/usr/bin:/bin/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` then the problem is here because the native mac php does not include mcrypt. Add your XAMP PHP to your paths variable should solve the problem,

```
export PATH=$PATH:\path\to\xamp\bin\php5.ver\bin
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already tried this solution but the error is the same. In my path there is no folder php5.v.., but that one is a file, so in my case the path should be /Applications/XAMPP/bin/php-5.5.11

Comment: SOLVED - path: /Applications/XAMPP/bin

Comment: From terminal try typing /Applications/XAMPP/bin/php5.5.11/bin php -m look in the output for mcrypt. I believe your missing the last /bin?